# How to splice all the items in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table and I'm using AngularJS to display it, there's a clear button where if clicked all the rows will be deleted from the table. I am using splice to do this but when I try to splice it, only the 1st and 3rd row get splice.

How do I splice all of the rows?

```
self.row.length = 3;
for (var index=0; index < self.row.length; index++) {
    if (self.row[index].DDelDetailId != 0) {
        self.deletedRow.push(angular.copy(self.row[index]));
    }
    console.log("index: "+index+" Rows: "+self.row.length)
    self.row.splice(index, 1)
}
```

I already looked at all the similar questions but none of them helped me. It can splice if the `self.row.length` is 1 but if it is greater than 1 it leaves 1 row.

Below is what was printed in the console log:

```
Index: 0 Rows: 3
Index: 1 Rows: 2
```

I push all the deleted row to `self.deletedRow` then if user clicks save then the deleted rows will be deleted in the database. Each row has a delete button so user can delete all rows or delete 1 specific row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're moving the index forward while deleting rows, you're skipping rows:
iteration 1:

```
index = 0
arr: [0, 1, 2]
arr.splice(0, 1) => arr: [1, 2] // deletes first item
```

iteration 2:

```
index = 1
arr: [1, 2]
arr.splice(1, 1) => arr: [1] // deletes second item
```

iteration 3:

```
index = 2
arr: [1]
arr.splice(2, 1) => arr [1] // tries to delete third item
```

If you delete the first item all the time, you won't skip anything:

```
arr.splice(0, 1)
```

It's also more efficient to remove all rows: `arr = []` or `arr.length = 0`,

Comment: This helped me the most since it explained why it was skipping rows almost all the answer was right. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

> if clicked all the rows will be deleted from the table

Why you are using splice for every row you can clear that whole array. So use `self.row=[]` instead of using `splice()`.

> As per the comment below: I actually push all the deleted row to self.deletedRow then if user clicks save then the delete rows

assign the row values to `self.deletedRow` before delete your all rows.

```
self.deleteAll=function()
{
self.deletedRow = self.row;
self.row = [];
}
```

this Above way for all rows

and this below way for selected rows

```
self.deleteSingleRow = function(currentObject)// currentObject is `ng-repeat` directive object and you should be pass to the `deleteSingleRow` in html  
{
self.deletedRow.push(currentObject);
//do your delete service call and rebind the `row` array
}
```

Comment: I actually push all the deleted row to `self.deletedRow` then if user clicks save then the delete rows will be deleted in the database. Each row has a delete button so user can delete all rows or delete 1 specific row.

Comment: @klent Now i have explained the simple logic for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using splice itself

Here is the working example for whole requirement

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
      app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
        var self = this;
        self.data = [{"Product":"Body Spray","Location":"USA","Dec-2017":"234","Jan-18":"789","Feb-18":"234","Mar-18":"789","Apr-18":"234"},{"Product":"Groceries","Location":"USA","Dec-2017":"234","Jan-18":"789","Feb-18":"234","Mar-18":"789","Apr-18":"234"},{"Product":"Ready Cook","Location":"USA","Dec-2017":"234","Jan-18":"789","Feb-18":"234","Mar-18":"789","Apr-18":"234"},{"Product":"Vegetables","Location":"USA","Dec-2017":"234","Jan-18":"789","Feb-18":"234","Mar-18":"789","Apr-18":"234"}];
        self.deletedData = [];
        self.duplicateData = angular.copy(self.data);
        self.clearData = function(element){
          if(element){
            var index = self.data.indexOf(element);
            if(index > -1){
              self.deletedData.push(angular.copy(element));
              self.data.splice(index, 1);     
            }
          }
          else{
            self.deletedData = angular.copy(self.data);
            self.data.splice(0, self.data.length);
          }
        };
        
        self.resetData = function(element){
          //The table order wont change
          self.data = angular.copy(self.duplicateData);
          
          //The table order will change in this
          /*angular.forEach(self.deletedData, function (item, index) {
              self.data.push(item);
          });*/
          
          self.deletedData = [];
        };
      });
    }());
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl as ctrl">
  <button ng-click="ctrl.clearData()">Delete All</button>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.resetData()">Reset All</button>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in ctrl.data[0] as header">
          {{ key }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="row in ctrl.data track by $index">
        <td data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in ctrl.data[0]">
          {{ row[key] }}
        </td>
        <td>
          <button ng-click="ctrl.clearData(row)">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because self.row.length is changing dynamically as you are splicing.
use a temp variable and store length of your array to delete all rows
e.g

```
var temp = self.row.length;
for(var index=0;index<temp;index++) {
  //splice
}
```